# How to access controls in windows form shown event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change the Visible state of controls from the form shown event.

I am reading the name of the controls from the database table and accessing it using `this.Controls["controlname"].Visible`. But some of the controls are not able to access from within this event. It is showing exception.

How  can I access the controls from form shown event?

Comment: What exception please...

Comment: @KingKing It is showing Null exception

Comment: an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would be helpful

Comment: The control dont belong in a child controls container?

Comment: just make sure that control is exist or the name of that control is the correct one. try to check the spelling of name of that control.

Comment: Are the controls really there? Are they subcontrols of other controls (e.g. Panels)?

Comment: Are you able to access the controls in any other context. ie. from any other event other than form shown event

Comment: @user1690835 I'm sure that you don't have any control with such a passed-in name. Why do you save control names in database? it sounds funny :)

Comment: @KingKing It is for user management. I want to show or hide controls based on user role. If I directly use the name, I am able to access the control. Proble is with this.Controls["controlname"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Controls.Find() to **search** for it.  As scheien pointed out, the control is probably inside a different container causing it not to be "found" with your original syntax.  Here's a quick example:

```
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ctlNameFromDatabase = "textBox1";

        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(ctlNameFromDatabase, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0)
        {
            // ... do something with "matches[0]" ...

            // you may need to CAST to a specific type:
            if (matches[0] is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = matches[0] as TextBox;
                tb.Text = "Hello!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name: " + ctlNameFromDatabase, "Control Not Found!");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

For MenuItems you'll have to flag the control name in the database as a "menu item" and then use this code, where `menuStrip1` is the name of your MenuStrip, to find them:

```
        string menuName = "copyToolStripMenuItem";
        ToolStripItem[] matches = menuStrip1.Items.Find(menuName, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0)
        {
            matches[0].Visible = true;
        }
```

The same code will work for ToolStrips as well.  For example, replace `menuStrip1` with `toolStrip1`.

Comment: I am using child windows and a container parent window. Above code is working in child windows but not in parent container window.

Comment: Controls.Find() can't find controls in other forms.  If you need to find controls in one of the child forms then you'll need a reference to that child form first, then call Controls.Find() against the child.

Comment: I want to show or hide menustrip and toolstrip items in the container form. Above code is not working for those items.